# Some grid items grows up compared to other due to different size content

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout, material-ui

I have a problem building an UI.

I'm trying to copy [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVy6c.png) mockup found on dribbble.

I'm using React with Material UI and this is why I'm stuck:

I should have a kind of card with defined height (because there is another card of same height aside) with a first section of icon, title and a subtitle. Under this line it should be a grid layout with 2 rows and 3 columns that should define 6 equal containers with undefined and variable height and width and that's it
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzNWH.png) is how my layout is shown at this point.

Now I should add the images of payment methods and **I would like that it will behave like container remain of it's width and height and the image resizes and scale to fill the container (keeping its ratio) but** [when I try to add the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDiaH.png) **the MUI item grow to fit the content (image) growing its height.** If you look at the last image you can see that the 1st row of the items is higher than the 2nd one. How can I fix that keeping the responsive layout?

Thank you all folks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid container md={5} xs={12} lg={6}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "purple",
          padding: 20,
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}>

        <Grid container xs={12} md={10} lg={10}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "grey",
            padding: 20
          }}>

          <Grid item xs={3} lg={3}
            style={{
              height: 120,
              padding: 10,
              backgroundColor: "black"
            }}>
            <div style={{ height: "100%", backgroundColor: "grey" }} />
            {/* today I'm so beautiful (: */}
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={9} lg={9}
            style={{
              height: 120,
              padding: 10,
              backgroundColor: "black"
            }}>
            <div style={{ height: "100%", backgroundColor: "red" }} />
          </Grid>

        </Grid>

        <Grid container xs={12} lg={10}
          style={{
            height: 200,
            backgroundColor: "green",
            padding: 5,
          }}>

          <Grid item xs={6} lg={4} style={styles.paymentCardContainer}>
            <div style={styles.paymentCard}>
              <img src={paypal} style={styles.imgResponsive2} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} lg={4} style={styles.paymentCardContainer}>
            <div style={styles.paymentCard}>
              <img src={visa} style={styles.imgResponsive2} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} lg={4} style={styles.paymentCardContainer}>
            <div style={styles.paymentCard} >
              <img src={mastercard} style={styles.imgResponsive2} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} lg={4} style={styles.paymentCardContainer}>
            <div style={styles.paymentCard} >

              <img src={wise} style={styles.imgResponsive2} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} lg={4} style={styles.paymentCardContainer}>
            <div style={styles.paymentCard}>
              <img src={stripe} style={styles.imgResponsive2} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} lg={4} style={styles.paymentCardContainer}>
            <div style={styles.paymentCard} >
              <img src={payoneer} style={styles.imgResponsive2} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

And here's the style:

```
const styles = {
  imgResponsive1: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    padding: 20,
    overflow: "hidden",
  },
  imgResponsive2: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "auto",
  },
  imgResponsive3: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "auto",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  center: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  paymentCardContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  paymentCard: {
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
}
```